# Query / Algorithm for finding One-to-many within a table

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create an algorithm to evaluate which columns within a single table may have a one-to-many relationship and possibly be parent/child.

Consider the following table:

```
Category | Subcategory | Product   | Description
A1       | BBB         | Batteries | Energizer 
A1       | BCB         | Plugs     | Safety Plugs
A2       | CDE         | TVs       | Samsung
A2       | CDE         | Monitors  | Dell
```

In this case, Category could be a parent of all columns.  Subcategory could be a parent of the other two columns.  And Products / Descriptions are 1-to-1.

I've tried comparing two columns with a count distinct by partition, but not able to really figure it out.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Could be as simple as two inner joins. What are the table definitions?

Comment: This table is just an example.  I'm looking to create a generalized version of this algorithm for data analysis.  Often we have tables which don't have a great deal of meta data.  And this is a part of data profiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query like this will do it:

```
select distinct 'Category' as parent, 'Subcategory' as child
from (select distinct category, subcategory from otm) as cols
group by category
having count(subcategory) > 1
union
select distinct 'Subcategory' as parent, 'Category' as child
from (select distinct category, subcategory from otm) as cols
group by subcategory
having count(category) > 1
union
select distinct 'Category' as parent, 'Product' as child
from (select distinct category, product from otm) as cols
group by category
having count(product) > 1
union
select distinct 'Product' as parent, 'Description' as child
from (select distinct product,description from otm) as cols
group by product
having count(description) > 1;
```

This example illustrates the technique with only a few selected pairs of columns, but it could be extended to include all pairs of columns.  The same technique could be extended to include multiple columns as the candidate parent keys, but the number of clauses to be unioned will blow up fast.  A good general solution would be to write something in a client language that pulls all the column names from the information schema and automatically creates the SQL to examine all combinations that you might be interested in.

Comment: Ok, i think this would work.  I would script the select portion and loop over the various column combinations to evaluate the whole table and store sample results separately.

Comment: I modified it for only a single column comparison and output the results to a table and its good enough for our purposes.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can calculate a probability by the ratio of distinct values in a column and the overall number of rows in the table.

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT category) / count(*) probability_category,
       count(DISTINCT subcategory) / count(*) probability_subcategory,
       count(DISTINCT product) / count(*) probability_product,
       count(DISTINCT description) / count(*) probability_description
       FROM elbat;
```

The higher the probability the higher the chance, that the column is independent of any other.

But this won't give you a definitive answer. And I doubt this is even possible. In the end that all depends on the semantics of the data, not on the actual data set (the logical relationships still are true even if there is no data at all in the table).

Comment: Yes, this is a good start.  I'd like to be able to flag the columns which have a high likelihood of being related.  And then the data analyst can review the outcome and determine if which are truly related or not.